Hölder's inequality - conjugate exponent condition
For given $p\in[1,\infty]$, we define the sequence spaces
$$
\ell^p:=\{x=(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset\mathbb{R}:\|x\|_p<\infty\}
$$
where
$$
\|x\|_p =\begin{cases}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p\right)^{1/p},&p\in[1,\infty)\\
\|x\|_\infty =\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|x_n|,&p=\infty.
\end{cases}
$$
Provided that $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ and $x\in\ell^p,y\in\ell^q$ it is well-known that Hölder's inequality holds, i.e.
$$
\|xy\|_1\leq \|x\|_p\|y\|_q.
$$
At the moment, I am wondering how sharp the conjugate exponent condition is. To be precise, provided that $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ and $y\notin\ell^q$ can I construct $x\in\ell^p$ such that
$$
\|xy\|_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_ny_n|=\infty?
$$

Yes, and this is a standard result. Search MSE for this.

Thank you for your comment. Just to clarify you mean the mean squared error?

MSE is the name of this site: Mathstackexchange -:)

True indeed :-)

Concerning your question, try to construct $x_n$ in terms of $y_n.$

True, but the question is how do you have an idea?

If $p=\infty$ this is easy by taking $x_n=1$, so assume $p<\infty$. There might be an easier way of doing it such as explicitly constructing $x_n$ in terms of $y_n$ (as suggested in the comments), but if we only want the existence of such a sequence $x_n$, here is a fun way to do it. Suppose that for all $x\in\ell^p$, we have $\lVert xy\rVert_1<\infty$. We show that $y\in\ell^q$. The assumption implies that $T:\ell^p\to\ell^1, (x_n)_n\mapsto (x_ny_n)_n$ is well defined. It is easy to see that this is closed, hence bounded by the closed graph theorem. If you already know that $(\ell^p)^*\cong\ell^q$, you can finish from here by composing $T$ with the bounded functional $\ell^1\to\Bbb C, (z_n)_n\mapsto \sum z_n$ to get that $\ell^p\to\Bbb C, (x_n)\mapsto \sum x_ny_n$ is bounded and its norm is $\lVert y\rVert_q$. Alternatively you can use some ideas from that proof here: Take $x\in\ell^p$ to be $x_n=y_n^{q-1}$ for $n\leq N$ and $x_n=0$ otherwise. Then from $\lVert T(x)\rVert_1\leq\lVert x\rVert_p\lVert T\rVert$ we get $(\sum_{k=1}^N|y_n|^q)^{1/q}\leq \lVert T\rVert <\infty$, hence $y\in \ell^q$.

Thank you for your answer. The first way is really elegant, I like it a lot! But I would like to prove it more elementary like you sketched in your second alternative. How could we prove without using the closed graph theorem that $|T|<\infty$?

The second approach still uses the first part because we need a uniform bound on the sums $\sum x_ny_n$. In fact, after thinking about it I don't see an elementary way of doing it (e.g. by explicitly constructing $x_n$ somehow), but there very well may be one
